# req.body undefined using post method

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

login.html(I have converted it to jade) is my login page which is opened at localhost:3000.
I send the form details to index.js(server).

Problem:
On console.log(username) I get output as undefined. Please help.
Have I used body-parser correctly ?

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('./Public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/tpl');
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("login");
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended : false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(req,res) {
    var username = req.body.name;
    console.log(username);
  });

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

html code: (login.html)

```
<html>
       <body>
          <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />
                <br />
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Create Profile" />
             </fieldset>
          </form>
          <script>
             var socket = io.connect("http://loacalhost:3000");
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look documentation of [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) you can notice this:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> busboy and connect-busboy multiparty and connect-multiparty formidable
>   multer

So you have to either change enctype="multipart/form-data" to for example enctype="application/json" or to use some other module.

Hope that I have helped you.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as useful and as answer to your question? I would really appreciate that.